# Node/express passing a route variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pass a object that I passed to a route, e.g.:

```
res.render('index', {myObj: myObj});
```

But then if I want to run a JS script in the index page how do I access this object inside the script, I looked it up and saw that I can put it inside the script using ejs e.g.:

```
var obj = "<%= myObj %>"
```

but then I cant put the script in a separate file because it is dependent on the ejs.

What is the right way to pass this parameter to my JS so that I can also put my script in a separate script file????

Thanks

Comment: So, what I always did, is define constants at the top of the document above all scripts and then just use them in the scripts loaded in from other files, I don't know if that's the best way to do that though

Comment: how do you define and use them?? for example the myObj tha I am passing to the html how would you define it as a constant in the html to use it??? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, I always define the values I want to pass to the client sides JS at the top of my HTML document, like this, and then load the scripts that use those variables in after the definition:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    /** constants from Express **/
    let myObj = <%- JSON.stringify(myObj) %>;
    //'-' must be used here not '=' after <% for it to work)
    let someString = "<%= someString %>";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    ...
<script src="scripts/someJS.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

scripts/someJS.js can now use the variables.

Comment: Hi, I don't know why but this works for someString but not for myObj, when I declare let myObj = <%= myObj %>; it stops my script.

Comment: Can you try this now?

Comment: Tried it the line of let myObj = <%= JSON.stringify(myObj) %>; has to have a - instead of a = (let myObj = <%- JSON.stringify(myObj) %>;) to work like Lawrence's answer and then it oes work as you have it for coding to an outside file, Dont know why it didn't work without the JSON.stringify does it work for you without it. Anyways thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If `myObj` is an object, presuming it is, use `JSON.stringify()`

```
<script>
    var myObj = <%- JSON.stringify(myObj) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, this works if the script is in the html file itself but how would I access myObj if my script is in its own file???

Answer (score 0):

I once did something similar by using `require.js`. `require.js` will load the .js file containing the script you want to run and also pass `myObj` into it.

---

#### server.js

```
res.render('index', {myObj: myObj});
```

#### index.ejs

```
// index.js is your separate .js file which is declared as entry point
<script data-main="index.js" src="<PATH_TO_REQUIRE_JS>"></script>
<script>
  requirejs.config({
    config: {
      // By default load any modules from this folder
      baseUrl: './js',
      // index must be used as name here in order to pass myObj into ./js/index.js
      "index": {
        "myObj": "<%= myObj %>"
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### index.js

```
var myObj = module.config().myObj;
```

---

- `<script data-main="../js/index.js"` defines your separate .js file as a module.
- `requirejs.config()` will pass the specified keys to the modules that they have been declared for.
- `module.config().<SOME_KEY>;` will give you the value of each specified key for each module.

Comment: Thanks allot for the answer, I didn't get it to work but I think I made a mistake going to try again, I found the answer by Luca a bit easier though, is there an advantage doing it this way??? Thanks

Comment: Code-wise Luca's answer is less complex, you are right. But it makes use of global variables which can cause troubles sometimes.

Comment: @Jack I just saw that I used the ```baseUrl``` option as well when calling ```requirejs.config({...});```. It is important to define this option because the ```config``` option just uses the name of files instead of the relative path in my example. I updated my answer using ```baseUrl```.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for the responses, I am learning allot.  I never doing something like this was so complex, you definitely have a very unique aproach.